# What is the term for a compound where one element exists in two oxidation states in the same molecule?

Tags: oxidation-state, terminology

Example nitrogen in $\ce{N2O}$ (−3 and +5). I'm pretty sure there's a term but I've forgotten what it is I thought it was disproportionation but this seems to only refer to a reaction

Comment: "Mixed oxide" is sometimes used to describe oxides where the central atom exists in more than one oxidation state. Another example is $\ce{Mn3O4}$, which exists in both the +2 and +3 states. See more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_oxide

Comment: When a species changes to two different oxidation states it's called "disproportionation" so could it be described as "disproportionate"?

Comment: What would you call a compound like $\ce{NH4NO3}$, where the nitrogen atoms are in differing oxidation states?

Comment: There's no such term and almost all organic compounds have oxidation state varying between atoms.